# How to set attributes while dynamically creating enum using EnumBuilder

Tags: c#, xml, enums

I have to create Enum dynamically from XML.
XML format is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Category xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Game>
    <Name>Tekken</Name>
    <Code>10</Code>
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Name>NFS</Name>
    <Code>20</Code>
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Name>FinalFa</Name>
    <Code>40</Code>
  </Game>
</Category>
```

I want to create Enum which looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum Category
{
    [EnumMember]
    Tekken = 10,
    [EnumMember]
    NFS = 20,
    [EnumMember]
    FinalFa = 40,
}
```

So far I have been able to create this:

```
 public enum Category
    {
        Tekken = 10,
        NFS = 20,
        FinalFa = 40,
    }
```

C# code used to generate the Enum:

```
   private static void Create()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName("EnumAssembly");
            AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            ModuleBuilder mb = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name + ".dll");
            EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("MyNamespace.Category", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

            FieldBuilder fb1 = eb.DefineLiteral("Tekken", 10);
            FieldBuilder fb2 = eb.DefineLiteral("NFS", 20);
            FieldBuilder fb3 = eb.DefineLiteral("FinalFa", 40);

            Type eType = eb.CreateType();
            asmBuilder.Save(asmName.Name + ".dll");

            foreach (object obj in Enum.GetValues(eType))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", eType, obj, ((int)obj));
            }
        }
```

How can I add the attributes [DataContract], [Flags] and [EnumMember] to my enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see, the `DefineLiteral` method returns a `FieldBuilder` (fb1, fb2, fb3). You can use [`SetCustomAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btz51t4a.aspx) on the FieldBuilder to set an attribute. The linked MSDN article has an example on how to use it. The gist of it though, would be to use a [`CustomAttributeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.customattributebuilder.aspx) to build your attribute, then give it to SetCustomAttribute.

Comment: I tried this approach and after setting attributes I created EnumAssembly dll. Then I referenced this dll in another project and checked the metadata for this enumeration(Go To Definition F12). But the attribute [EnumMember] was not visible. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I missed adding the namespace System.Runtime.Serialization. After adding it [EnumMember] attribute was visible.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure but something like this:

```
Type myType = typeof(DataContract);
ConstructorInfo myInfo = myType.GetConstructor();

eb.SetCustomAttribute(myInfo);
```